# Show that $v_1$ is the projection of $C$ onto the direction $u_1$ scaled by $1/\sigma_1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U, \Sigma, V^T$ be the SVD of the matrix $C$
where the diagonal entries of $Sigma$ are arranged from largest to
smallest. Let $U = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & \cdots & u_m\end{bmatrix}$ be the
$m$ columns of $U$ and
$V = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_n\end{bmatrix}$ be the $n$ columns of
$V$. Show that $v_1$ is the projection of $C$ onto the
direction $u_1$ scaled by $1/\sigma_1$.

Proof: By definition, $C = U\Sigma V^T$. Note that $C$ may be rewritten as
$$ C = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sigma_i u_i v_i^T$$
where $\sigma_i$ are the eigenvalues along the diagonal of $\Sigma$. I want to show that $proj_{u_1} C = \dfrac{1}{\sigma_1}v_1$.

It's been a minute since I have done linear algebra. How would I find such projection for this problem?

Comment: I have never heard of projecting a matrix onto a vector. Are you sure that you copied the problem statement correctly? If so, could you clarify what exactly you mean by "projection" in this context?

Comment: I believe this article does a good job explaining what "projection" means in this context: https://towardsdatascience.com/svd-8c2f72e264f

Comment: The article doesn't answer my essential question. I am trying to figure out what you mean by "the projection of $C$" onto anything, since typically it is *vectors* rather than matrices that are projected in this context.

Comment: Perhaps decomposition of C into projection operators?

Comment: may we know the source of the question? in particular, do you have references where $proj_{u_1}C$ is defined?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I was just using the definition on wiki

Comment: unfortunately I can't find it, can you include the definition?

Comment: Okay. I spoke with my instructor and he says that he wants an answer that derives v1 in terms of u1. He says to use matrice manipulation. Basically solve for v1 and simplify $U$ and $\Sigma$.

Comment: $u_1^TC = \sigma_1 v_1^T$, so $v_1^T=\frac{1}{\sigma_1}u_1^TC$, or equivalently, $v_1=\frac{1}{\sigma_1}Cu_1$

Comment: That's what I computed too. @player100 post it as an answer so I can give you the bounty reward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_1^TC = \sigma_1v_1^T$$

So,
$$v_1^T={1\over\sigma_1}u_1^TC$$

Equivalently,
$$v_1={1\over\sigma_1}C^Tu_1$$

Note, I assume that the projection of $C$ on $u_1$ is meant as $C^Tu_1$, and I forgot to take the transpose of $C$ in the comment.